# How is the best way to mask an element for be a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, if which are the best way to make a link some element, for example i have so many images and i want to be they links, the traditional way that i know is this:

```
<a href="someplace.html><img src="myimage.jpg" ></a>
```

that is the traditional way but, i need do this for all images that i want to be links, so early i'm do this with jquery library:

```
<img src="cats.jpg" class="link-cat">
```

and for make this a link:

```
$('.link-cat').hover(function(){$(this).css('cursor','pointer');},function(){$(this).css('cursor','pointer');}).on('click',function(){windows.location.href="http://www.cats.com";})
```

this closely be more code but when i have many images i feel this help me more

so i want to ask wheter is the best way to make a link some element not just an image

thanks.

Comment: Use CSS.  `cursor: pointer`.  Or, better yet, use `wrapAll()` to create actual links.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap them all in an `<a>` tag if you want users to see the URL in browser status area and use default cursor for `<a>`

```
$('.link-cat').each(function(){ 
     $(this).wrap('<a>').parent().attr('href',this.src);
});
```

As for your approach to set the css using jQuery it would be much simpler doing it in stylesheet with a CSS rule for the image class and using `:hover` selector

reference: **[wrap() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**